# Why the static variable is not set to 1000

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a static variable in my class , which I instantiate in the cpp file to value 1000.

```
class Container
{
private: 
    static long GLOBALID;
    long MyID;
public:

    Container();
    long GetId();   
};
```

The code for cpp file.

```
long Container::GLOBALID = 1000;

Container::Container()
{
    MyID = GLOBALID++;

}

long Container::GetId()
{
    return MyID;
}
```

When I print the ID value of container objects, they keep incrementing.

My question is that when I create a new object I instantiate the static varible to value 0f 1000 so why does it keep incrementing with each object created?

Comment: because you increment it on each object construction ...

Comment: @bolov but when i create a new object than i again set it to 1000 in the cpp file

Comment: "when i create a new object i instantiate the static varible to value 0f 1000"  - static variables can only be instantiated once , which happens on program startup for this one

Answer (score 4):

With each new Container object created, you increment the `Container::GLOBALID` number by 1. This is due to the fact that you call `MyID = GLOBALID++` inside the Container constructor, which returns the GLOBALID and then increments it, see [prefix and postfix increments](https://dev.to/somedood/the-difference-between-x-and-x-44dl)